# Cordova 3.7 Not Honoring 'AutoHideSplashScreen'

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

Similar questions to this have been asked in the past, but I believe this may be only related to Cordova 3.7 for iOS.

I have installed the most up-to-date SplashScreen Plugin from Apache, and have the following in my Config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0.25" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

I am attempting to use this JS to dismiss the Splash Screen:

```
setTimeout(function() {
     navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 20000);
```

Cordova does not seem to be honoring any of these preferences/commands, as the splash screen fades immediately and shows the web view (which is not done loading).

Does anyone know of a workaround to lengthen the duration of the splash screen?

Thanks.

Comment: May seem like a stupid question for you, but are you sure that your 1 second timeout just isn't too quick?

Comment: I have tried 20 seconds, and it still dismisses within 1 second of the app launching.

Comment: Do you run this code AFTER deviceready event?

Comment: Yes I did. I wiped the project and saw that it was having trouble reading the SplashScreen plugin. It was giving me error messages once I performed cordova prepare that did not show up initially, such as "CDVPlugin class CDVSplashScreen (pluginName: SplashScreen) does not exist." and "ERROR: Plugin 'SplashScreen' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml." Re-dragging the SplashScreen files into Xcode/checking to see if they were linked did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved includin in config.xml the next prefrences

```
 <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
 <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.3" />
 <vs:platformSpecificValues />
```

In the html page

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 5000);
}
```